# How does Google store the index?

Tags: indexing

Lately I have been reading about web crawling, indexing and serving.  I have found some information on the [Google Web Masters Tool - Google Basics](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=70897&rd=1) about the process that Google does to crawl the Web and serve the searches.
What I am wondering is how they save all those indexs?  I mean, that's a lot to store right? How do they do it?

Thanks

Comment: Data centers: http://www.google.com/corporate/datacenter/index.html

Comment: Hi Alex.  Thanks for the comment.  I was wondering how to store all those indexs in a database? Which engine are they using?

Comment: As a joke, this question is something like _What's the recepy for Coca Cola?_

Comment: TeraGoogle? It sounds like something developed in-house: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_platform#Software

Comment: @Alex Reynolds: Thanks for that link. That helps :).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm answering myself because I found some interesting stuff that talks about Google index:

- In Google Webmasters YouTube Channel, Matt Cutts give us some references about the architecture behind Google Index: [Google Webmaster YouTube Channel](http://www.youtube.com/user/GoogleWebmasterHelp#p/u/43/GYB1ROttwFA)
- One of those references, and from my point of view a worth reading, is this one: [The Anatomy of a Large-Scale Hypertextual Web Search Engine](http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/334.pdf)

This helped me to understand it better, and I hope it help you too!

Answer (score 0):

They use a variety of different types of data stores depending on the type of information. Generally, they don't use SQL because it has too much overhead and isn't very compatible with large-scale distribution of information.

Google actually developed their own data store that they use for large read-mostly applications such as Google Earth and the search engine's cache. This supports distributing information over a very large number of computers with each piece of information stored on three or four different computers. This allows them to use cheap hardware -- if one computer fails, the others immediately begin restoring all the data it held to the appropriate number of copies